# Two Different ways to create custom elements in Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, polymer-2.x

I am new to Polymer. I have seen that there are two ways to create a custom element in Polymer(v2.0).

One is

```
<script>
     Polymer({
         is: 'custom-element',
         properties: {...},
         ....
     });
</script>
```

The other one is

```
<script>
    class CustomElement extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return  'x-foo' }
    }
    customElements.define(XFoo.is, XFoo);
</script>
```

Is there any difference between these two methods? In the second method, one can easily `extends` any existing element. How to do it using the first method?

Comment: The first definition belongs to Polymer 1.x  and second is Polymer 2.x version. If one app has both components then this is hybrid Polymer app. Consider, 2.x supports 1.x 's components.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the confusion. How can one extend a component in polymer 1.x

Comment: Which platform you work 2.x? Extend a Polymer 1.x ? I didn't understand exactly.  Please explain with more details

Comment: @HakanC I was wondering how to extends a class in Polymer 1.x?